# Initializing an Array of Objects using a Constructor that takes in Arguments for creating the Object

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, constructor

I have a System consisting of n-Particles. A Particle object can be initialized by using a constructor that takes in several parameters (say doubles) as arguments.

```
Particle p(para1, para2 ... , paraN);
```

I now have a System which needs an array of n-Particles. I want to build a constructor that takes in the number of objects along with the Particle parameters and creates an n-Particle array.

I tried the following:

```
class System {

public:
    Particle p[]; //declare dynamic array

    System() {}
    //Constructor
    System(int n, para1, para2 ... , paraN)
    {
        Particle p[n]; //Particle array of size n
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
                Particle temp(para1, para2 ... , paraN);
                p[i] = temp;
            }
        }
};
```

The program doesn't compile and gives the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘p[i] = tempp’
note: candidate is:
note: Particle& Particle::operator=(const Particle&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Particle(double, double, double,     double)’ to ‘const Particle&’
```

I am new to C++ and OOP in general. Any help on how to overcome this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that the array p inside the constructor shadows the attribute p of the same name. Use something like `p = new Particle[n]` instead.

Comment: Specifically, the comment //Particle array of size n does not mean both P[n] mean the same thing

Comment: IS this the exact code with the error: the error says no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘p[i] = tempp’ and your code says p[i] = temp;

Comment: The syntax in your code is completely invalid, there will be plenty more compile (and runtime) errors than what you’ve shown.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `p[i] = temp`, the compiler looks for an overload of the assignment operator in the Particle class with the signature:

```
Particle& Particle::operator=(const Particle&)
```

The intent of this is for you to define how the assignment of an object works depending on its class. Here you can do attribute assignment or the semantics of assigning a Particle that you define. This is particularly useful when you have dynamically allocated data in objects where the copying of a pointer may not be the correct behavior.

Take a look at this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/ 
It not only explains why and when you need an assignment operator but also a copy constructor.

Comment: Why are we getting the error no known conversion from ‘Particle(double, double, double,     double)’ to ‘const Particle&’ then?